# GMail - notify until read?

Tags: email, notifications, gmail, motorola-droid

I'm a new Android user with a Motorola X2 running Android 2.3.4 and the GMail app version 2.3.5.2.

I have a set of labels set up and custom notifications enabled for those that I need to have distinguished. I need a constant alert until the message is marked as read.

I have been looking at the [GMail Label Notifier](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.hubris.gmailnotifierpro&hl=en) app but it doesn't appear to have the necessary option. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that you need the notification to not be dismissed when you open the Gmail app?

Comment: I'm after an audio / vibration (preferably both) alert which will not dismiss until I have read a message.

Answer (score 1):

The Google's own [Gmail](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.gm) app doesn't have this functionality built-in.

Unfortunately with the latest version of the app (v2.3.5.2 as of this writing,) Google have disabled access to Gmail's data by other 3rd-party apps and widgets.  This was most likely done for security purposes.  The side-effect is that none of the 3rd-party apps on the Market that need access to your Gmail accounts (notifiers, widgets, etc.) stopped working.

Your best bet is to find an alternate e-mail app that has such a feature.  I've used [K-9 Mail](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fsck.k9), but I don't remember any settings that would give you non-stop alerts. You could try submitting a feature request on K-9's [support site](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/issues/list).